# get minimal value for each multiindex pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I cannot figure how to filter a multiindexed dataframe keeping only one row per index.

Here are my data:
    import random
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

```
A = np.array(['ID1', 'ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'ID3', 'ID3', 'ID4', 'ID4'])
B = np.array([1, 2, 2, 5, 3, 7, 12, 9])
C = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
D = list('abcdefgh')

df1 = pd.DataFrame(zip(A, B, C, D), columns=['ID', 'trial', 'C', 'D'])
df1.set_index(['ID', 'trial'], inplace=True)

a = np.array(['ID2', 'ID3', 'ID4'])
b = np.array([2,2,11])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(zip(a,b), columns = ['sub', 'attempt'])
```

df1:

```
          C  D
ID  trial      
ID1 1      1  a
    2      2  b
ID2 2      3  c
ID3 5      4  d
    3      5  e
    7      6  f
ID4 12     7  g
    9      8  h
```

df2:

```
sub  attempt
0  ID2        2
1  ID3        2
2  ID4       11
```

And I would like to keep from df1, only the data that matches the df2 with a condition on 'attempt', it should keep the row with the closest value for df1.trial to df2.attempt:

```
          C  D
ID  trial      
ID2 2      3  c
ID3 3      5  e
ID4 12     7  g
```

I found a really dirty way (with many "for" iteration...), but I feel like there is something more beautiful to do.

Another thing I would like to do, is to keep only the first row of each multiindex in df1:

```
          C  D
ID  trial      
ID1 1      1  a
ID2 2      3  c
ID3 5      4  d
ID4 12     7  g
```

But also here, I only get dirty code, by creating another one.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = df2['sub']
idx = pd.Series(
    df1.index.get_level_values('trial'),
    df1.index
).groupby(level=0).idxmin()
df1.loc[idx].query('ID in @s')

           C  D
ID  trial      
ID2 2      3  c
ID3 3      5  e
ID4 9      8  h
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it gives me a first direction. However in my case the column 'C' or 'D' are not necessarily ordered, this is why I want the first line. Also 'C' and 'D' can be not integer or string, but objects.

Comment: Updated answer @POINTEAG